# Python list is not the same reference

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
L=[1,2]

L is L[:]

False
```

Why is this False?

Comment: Try this, it could be insightful too: `L[:] is L[:]`

Comment: Reserve `is` testing for checking against None or other singletons (like classes or modules), otherwise, you are most likely interested in `==` testing (and yes, I know `1 is 1` generally returns True in the CPython world, but that doesn't make it a good idea).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`L[:]` (slice notation) means: Make a copy of the entire list, element by element.

So you have two lists that have identical content, but are separate entities. Since `is` evaluates object identity, it returns `False`.

`L == L[:]` returns `True`.

Answer (score 6):

When in doubt ask for `id` ;)

```
>>> li = [1,2,4]
>>> id(li)
18686240
>>> id(li[:])
18644144
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The **getslice** method of list, which is called when you to L[], returns a list; so, when you call it with the ':' argument, it doesn't behave differently, it returns a new list with the same elements as the original.

```
>>> id(L)
>>> id(L[:])
>>> L[:] == L 
True
>>> L[:] is L
False
```